# How do you create a .netrc file?

Tags: swift, xcode, sdk, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm attempting to download the Mapbox Maps SDK for ios but I'm having trouble understanding how to create a .netrc file. I'm supposed to store my secret token to download the SDK and I can't add the SDK dependency with Cocoapods until I do this first. Anyone know how to go about this?

Here's the installation page for reference.

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency

The format for the .netrc file is as follows:

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password <INSERT SECRET API TOKEN>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 20):

**Instruction how to install Mapbox into you system**

If you have problems with installation Mapbox regarding official guide https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/

You can use next tips.

---

To create .netrc file do next

1. Fire up Terminal
2. cd ~ (go to the home directory)
3. touch .netrc (create file)
4. open .netrc (open .netrc)
5. Set required data.
6. Save

.netrc file should be like this

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password <secret_key_created_from_your_mapbox_account>
```

---

If you created `.netrc` file regarding this instruction, mapbox cocoapods should install.

Answer (score 4):

CD to $HOME directory

```
$ cd ~
```

Create .netrc file

```
$ vi .netrc
```

Then use vi or any other editor and change the content of the file `.netrc` to

```js
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password <YOUR SECRET TOKEN>
```

Make sure to replace `<YOUR SECRET TOKEN>`

Comment: Thank you! It says I have an existing file. If I press (R) to recover it and then copy and paste the information above, how do I save the terminal to reflect these changes? Thank you for your incredibly helpful information!