# Mapbox ios sdk won't install for flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, terminal, cocoapods, mapbox-ios

I have checked nearly everything. My `.netric` file is in the **home directory** and it is in the right format. My secret key has `download:read` checked off when I made it, but still, every time I want to download the podfile, it gives me this error:

```
[!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK
[!] /Users/walidsheykho/opt/anaconda3/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/tm/<folder details>/file.zip https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.3.0/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.11.2 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'
```

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--     0 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized

I haven't had much experience downloading pods through flutter, so that might be the reason but it still didn't work even after I closed flutter and entered the directory on its own. What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a file named .netrc in your home directory, if it doesn't already exist. To check if it exists, perform step 2. and 3, otherwise proceed with the steps below.
2. Open home directory in terminal

   ```
   cd
   ```
3. Create .netrc file

   ```
   touch .netrc
   ```
4. Open .netrc file

   ```
   open .netrc
   ```
5. When the file is open, copy/paste this and set your secret password:

   machine api.mapbox.com

   login mapbox

   password REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SECRET_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
6. Save the file

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue. The documentation says:

> Create a file named `.netrc` in your home directory if it doesn’t
> already exist, then add the following lines to the end of the file

```
machine api.mapbox.com
  login mapbox
  password PRIVATE_MAPBOX_API_TOKEN
```

For more infos, please visit the [package's documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios#installation)

> Check this link for [How do you create a .netrc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200786/how-do-you-create-a-netrc-file)